# backlight in android

Tags: android

In my android app , I have a menu for backlight options ,and I want that when the user selects    one like " during this operation " to have the backlight on during that operation. Could I be be shown a way of accomplishing this . My problem is the that I don't know how to manipulate the backlight and how to properly arrange this in  the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check [android.os.PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

You probably should also have WAKE_LOCK permission in manifest

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep the screen awake while on a particular activity, please see [Force Screen On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on)