# Black screen is displaying in Android

Tags: android

I opened my application after I am not doing any kind of operation. I leave the mobile 5 min. After 5 min when I touch the my application it is showing black screen. Is there any way to avoid this idle state?

Comment: Unless you have some code you need us to help with, this question is not programming related.

Comment: Do you mean stop the device from going asleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do. Use: `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` in your onCreate method.

There is another way, called a WakeLock, but you really shouldn't use that unless you know what you're doing. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on/2134602#2134602) from one of the Android designers for more information about WakeLocks and why you shouldn't use them unless you're careful.