# Android disable screen timeout while app is running

Tags: android

Is there a way to disable the screensaver while my app is running?

The dimming of the screen is what I mean.

Comment: What about using `View.setKeepScreenOn()`[link][1]?. I've never used it myself though.


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn%28boolean%29

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force Screen On](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712849/how-do-i-keep-the-screen-on-in-my-app/24261889#24261889

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You want to use something like this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: this makes it for the running activity or the whole app?

Comment: @MayurR.Amipara yeah I think this is the case here

Comment: If I write this code in Application class onCreate() method then will it work for whole app ?

Comment: If No then How can I keep whole app screen on by inserting less code instead of adding that line to each of the activity.

Comment: @Jayesh: You can create a baseActivity and write this code in onCreate Method and extend all activity from baseActivity.

Answer (score 110):

I used:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

to disable the screen timeout and

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

to re-enable it.

Answer (score 97):

There is also a XML way that Google recommends:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
```

Check [Google Slides](https://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/W_0300_CodingforLife-BatteryLifeThatIs.pdf) - Slide 16.

> "Wakelocks are costly if forgotten (...) Consider using
>   android:keepScreenOn to ensure correctness"

Comment: For the ones who don't have time to read linked pdf: "Wakelocks are costly if forgotten", "Consider using android:keepScreenOn to ensure correctness".

Comment: @lenrok258 Added to the answer ;-)

Comment: While using `PowerManager.newWakeLock` and `getWindow().addFlags` didn't work for some reason, this did.

Comment: please keep in mind that `getWindow().addFlags` has to be run from within a `context.runOnUiThread`

Answer (score 2):

In a View, in my case a SurfaceView subclass, you can set the screen on always on. I wanted the screen to stay on while this view was still drawing stuff.

```
public class MyCoolSurfaceView extends SurfaceView { 
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow (){
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.setKeepScreenOn(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow(){
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    this.setKeepScreenOn(false);
}
```

Comment: That is actually more complicated than needed.  Just call setKeepsScreenOn(true) anywhere, and the framework will automatically take care of keeping the screen on when your window is being shown.

Answer (score 2):

Its importante to note that these methods all must be run from the UI thread to work.  See [changing KeepScreenOn from javascript in Android cordova app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406722/changing-keepscreenon-from-javascript-in-android-cordova-app)

Answer (score 2):

Simple add below line into your `MainActivity` and your App never turn lights off.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 2):

1.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);is best solution for Native Android.
2. if you want to do with React android application then please use the below code.

```
@ReactMethod
    public void activate() {
        final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this at onStart

> ```
>     PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
>     wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "no sleep");
>     wakeLock.acquire();
> ```

And this at you manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Don't forget to

```
wakeLock.release();
```

at onStop

Comment: `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` allows the screen to go off.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by acquiring a Wake Lock.

I didn't tested it myself, but [here](http://android.voxisland.com/code_examples/How_to_stop_screen_from_dimming_by_enforcing_wake_lock.rhtml) is a small tutorial on this.

Comment: No no no. Wake locks are easily misused and can drain the user's battery if not used very carefully. Use `View#setKeepScreenOn` or its xml layout attribute equivalent, `android:keepScreenOn="true"`

Comment: @adamp: The OP did not indicate whether his app is an activity or a service. An activity should use the mechanism you cite. A service should use a `WakeLock`.

Comment: thanks its not a service. its similar to a picture viewer and i just dont want the screen to be dimmed.

Comment: @adamp: your mention of `android:keepScreenOn="true"` is the only valid answer for activities in my opinion. Stay away from wakelocks unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Not just Activities but any sort of UI that shows a window. The accepted answer of using the corresponding window flag is equally valid.

Comment: Simply setting the keeoScreenOn flag ony prevents the screen from turning off - it doesn't prevent the screen from dimming!

Comment: This website is no longer accessible.  Any answers are best put into the content of your post (even if not your content as you can attribute it to the author)

Comment: The posted link in this answer now leads to a porn site.

Answer (score 0):

this is the best way to solve this

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: why the need for FLAG_FULLSCREEN to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

is the better way to handle this if we want to make any particular screen awake all the time otherwise we have to handle yourself when to enable it and to disable  it

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure SetSleep(aEnable:Boolean);
var
    vFlags: integer;
begin
    vFlags := TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON or
        TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
        TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
        TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;

    if aEnable then
    begin
      CallInUIThread (   // uses FMX.Helpers.Android
      procedure
      begin
        TAndroidHelper.Activity.getWindow.setFlags (vFlags, vFlags);
      end );
    end
    else
      CallInUIThread (
      procedure
      begin
        TAndroidHelper.Activity.getWindow.clearFlags (vFlags);
      end );
end;
```