# Disable screen timeout Android phone/tablet

Tags: android, sleep

I want to completely disable the screen timeout.
You can set a anti sleep in your application code, but it wont disable the auto sleep of Android that you can set from 15 sec to 30 min, also the programs that i downloaded from the market cant disable the 30 min auto screen sleep limit.

I want to run a AJAX webpage in the browser that has to be visible at all times, its connected to power, so power is no issue.

Answer (score 16):

There is a XML way that Google recommends:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
```

Check http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/CodingLifeBatteryLife.html slide 16.

Or

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this](http://www.tutorials-android.com//code_examples/How_to_stop_screen_from_dimming_by_enforcing_wake_lock.rhtml) * (warning * link to expensive course)
Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195682/android-disable-screen-timeout-while-app-is-running) (FREE Google tutorial - use this link) can be helpful.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to about tablet or about phone in your device settings, go to build number, tap build number rapidly 7 times to enable developer options, click back button, open developer options, click stay awake and you are now done; your screen will never sleep. Be smart and don't play around in developer options, you can very easily destroy your device.