# Programmatically disable screen timeout

Tags: android

From this post, [Android disable screen timeout while app is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195682/android-disable-screen-timeout-while-app-is-running), I can disable screen timeout by

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

My question is am I safely enable screen timeout by

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: Doesn't [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) do what you want? I'm sure this is the preferred way.

Comment: I read some post here saying 'WakeLock' drain battery of the phone. I am not sure which one is the preferred way. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want the screen to time out after you've closed your application? Or is something inside your application going to reset the screen timeout so that it will happen even while your app is running?

If the former I don't think you need to do anything, when you're app is stopped the screen timeout will return to normal.

If the latter it seems like the snippet you've provided would do the trick. But I have no experience with it so I couldn't be certain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work - it's how I do it in PocketSat3, though I don't toggle FLAG_FULLSCREEN (of course, that said - that app doesn't use FLAG_FULLSCREEN...)

Unlike using WakeLock, doing it this way doesn't require any permissions - though I have to admit it's not completely clear to me that is a Good Thing.