# How to deactivate stand by mode in Android?

Tags: android

Are there any way to deactivate the standby mode programatically?

In my Android App Im doing a task that I cannot let the device get in that mode, is it  possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you studied http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195682/android-disable-screen-timeout-while-app-is-running

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on. As mentioned in this link, don't use PowerManager or WakeLock - just set `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`. Flagged as duplicate.

Comment: Please explain, in much greater detail, what this "task" is, so that we can give you accurate advice.

Comment: Thank you, by the above links.

Comment: I found my answer in the link posted by Nick.