# How to keep screen always on android

Tags: android

I am Building a android application in which i want screen(activity) not locked after some time means application screen always on.How can i do this in my application for all screen keep always on.means no screen ssaver no lock screen overcome in my application.

Comment: You can refer to this post, next time search.

[Solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712849/how-do-i-keep-the-screen-on-in-my-app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try below code:-

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

or

```
import android.os.PowerManager;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /* This code together with the one in onDestroy() 
     * will make the screen be always on until this Activity gets destroyed. */
    final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    this.mWakeLock.acquire();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    this.mWakeLock.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

for more info see below links:-

[How do I keep the screen on in my App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712849/how-do-i-keep-the-screen-on-in-my-app)

[Android disable screen timeout while app is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195682/android-disable-screen-timeout-while-app-is-running)

Comment: thankyou sir one more question in i want when phone start my application run with phone boot.doese not exit from my application while phone switch off

Comment: @user3541223 not understand your requirement.

Comment: My requirement is when android phone is turned on run my application only on phone startup.and user never exit from my application until phone is turned off

Answer (score 2):

simply add this line in `onCreate` method

> getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

It will keeps screen in active state.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below,

```
protected PowerManager.WakeLock wakelock;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstances) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.wakelock= pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        this.wakelock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.wakelock.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

don't forget to add the following permission in manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the ways to keep the screen on:
http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html