# Why does my AsyncTask file download fail when trying to download a large file?

Tags: android

I am trying to download a 600 MB file using an AsyncTask. If I execute my code on a real-world device, it works, but only if I "keep an eye on it" by not allowing the screen to remain off for any length of time, however, if I do not do this and just leave the device on its own, when I go to check on it a few minutes later, the progress dialog is gone and the file it has downloaded is only a fraction of the size it should be. My guess it that it has something to do with the phone putting WiFi to sleep after the screen's being off for a certain amount of time.

How do I fix this?

Here is the relevant code:

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();


            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file.zip");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;

    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

         mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try to stick with existing implementation. The downloadManager exists to do stuff like this for you, effortlessly: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: API Level is too high, need more backward compatibility... thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807634/disable-keep-screen-on) question describes how to keep the screen on so the phone does not go to sleep. If you are trying to download files 600mb+, you might consider putting your application into some type of [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) as this would potentially take a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use [Download Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) if your target SDK is high enough.

Comment: API Level is too high, need more backward compatibility... thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using Wi-Fi connection, which can be disconnected as soon as screen is off. You can check this in:

1. Settings-> Wireless and Networks -> Wi-Fi Setting
2. Click , select `Advanced`
3. Click on "Wi-Fi sleep policy" and select "never".

But you should consider using [Download Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) for newer devices (with Android 2.3+).