# Is there a way to limit the time the screen is on with FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON on Android?

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I don't want to use a WakeLock.
Is there a simple way to limit the time the screen is on using [`FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

Comment: You could use `Hander.postDelayed(...)` (or another delayed-execution option), and use the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807634/disable-keep-screen-on) to disable the keep_screen_on. You could use it in conjunction with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756768/turn-off-screen-on-android/6757206#6757206) to actually shut the screen off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the docs here : [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen)

than you see that you don't need to take care about this.
But you can, see:

> Note: You don't need to clear the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag unless you
>   no longer want the screen to stay on in your running application (for
>   example, if you want the screen to time out after a certain period of
>   inactivity). The window manager takes care of ensuring that the right
>   things happen when the app goes into the background or returns to the
>   foreground. But if you want to explicitly clear the flag and thereby
>   allow the screen to turn off again, use clearFlags():
>   getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON).

You could use this in conjunction with a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html), [post delayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) on the Handler,
which is the Android way to go, or with a TimerTask, which would be the 
more Java way.

Example:

```
    final long FIVE_MINUTES = 1000*60*5;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, FIVE_MINUTES);
```

Hope it helps.