# How to control the Screen Power Saver mode?

Tags: android, appsettings

In my application i want add this feature .

After open the application before closing the application i don't want allow to go into the power saver mode of the device. How can i manage this. even user can't doing anything on the screen (even it is in idle). after closing my application allow to get power saver mode.

**Edit**  i got the solution for this Query..

Comment: some thing lie WAKE_LOCK is there. I don't know exactly but google it.

Comment: i saw this in the sdk, is it correct? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

Comment: yes, it may be, just check what it is do, I think its prevent your app from going to in sleep mode.

Comment: sorry, i got answer from this i googled after [Force Screen On upto closing application ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on/2134602#2134602

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this keyword for your layout:

```
FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
```

Comment: than you nagi, already i go-ogled for question i got the solution from that link i posted above at my question , anyway thanks...

Answer (score 0):

add this code

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```