# Android Disable black screen

Tags: java, android

I need to disable the lock screen and at the same time the black screen..
I need to do this in the onStart of my service.

with this disable the lock screen, this works well:

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            lock.disableKeyguard();
```

how disable also the black screen?
I tried this  but do not work...

```
PowerManager pm2 = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
       PowerManager.WakeLock wakel = pm2.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "AttvaSchermo");
       wakel.acquire();
```

or in the activity..

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on/2134602#2134602)

Comment: I already tried ... but the screen stays black

Comment: You will need a manifest permission to enable a wakelock, and do heed Hackbod's concerns mentioned in Andrei's link.  FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON is tied to the visibility of a UI so probably wouldn't apply to a service.