# disallow save power

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force Screen On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on)

I need block the save power of device when my app is runs. No problem if screen goes down (my app is an audio app). I read about power manager and I discover this (that keep screen on). How disallow save power to device when my app runs?

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to *carefully* use a partial `WakeLock`, as is discussed in [the `PowerManager` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html). `acquire()` it when your audio starts playing, and `release()` it when the audio stops.