# Screen dimming/locking prevention android

Tags: android

I am using this code to prevent dimming/locking screen, it is perfectly working for prevention of locking, but dimming effect is not prevented yet. please tell me some way out to prevent dimming also

```
protected void setScreenLock(boolean on){


  if(mWakeLock == null){
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK |
                                    PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, TAG);
    }
    if(on){
     mWakeLock.acquire();
    }else{
        if(mWakeLock.isHeld()){
            mWakeLock.release();
        }
     mWakeLock = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
View root = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
if (root != null)
    root.setKeepScreenOn(true);
```

to your `if` part. This won't allow the screen to be dimmed.

Comment: this is helpful, with this neither the screen is dimming nor locking, but what i have to make the screen again able to lock or dim

Comment: Call `mWakeLock.release();` and `root.setKeepScreenOn(false);` when you want it to allow it to dim or lock.

Comment: public void setWindowDim(boolean dim)   getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  View root = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  if (root != null)
  {
   if (!dim) {
     root.setKeepScreenOn(true);
     
   }
   else {
    root.setKeepScreenOn(false);
   }
  }
  
 }

Comment: now i m using this function, root.setKeepScreenOn(true) is working fine but root.setKeepScreenOn(false) is not working

Comment: Are you passing dim as `true`?

Comment: NO, when i want to prevent dimming, m passing dim as false

Comment: When you want to allow to dim you have to change `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` to `getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use WakeLock at all (remove your current code and you can also get rid of related permission from your Manifest file) - this is incorrect (in most cases) approach. Use `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` flag in your `onCreate()` to tell framework to manage this for you. [Doc reads](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON):

> Window flag: as long as this window is visible to the user, keep the
>   device's screen turned on and bright.

like this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: but with this screen will always remain on, what I should use to release the screen_on effect

Comment: Screen will be only on when your activity is visible. If you put it i.e. in background, then screen will go off if needed without you doing anything. And here I found is the same answer from Android dev @Google: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2134602/1235698